# Cannot resolve symbol ReceiveUpdatesIntentService

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I'm trying to implement the example code of developers google in my app.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

I'm using all the files but in the AndroidManifest I have an error that sais me It cannot resolve symbol ***ReceiveUpdatesIntentService***. The code is all the same that the zip of google. The only change is the next.

The Manifest of Google:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.android.location.ReceiveUpdatesIntentService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

My Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name="com.nikolay.app.ReceiveUpdatesIntentService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

I have only change the package. What is the error??

Thank you friends.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a google service metadata into a manifest.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```